# Python: Extract time from a file path

Tags: python, file, datetime

I would like to find a general way to extract the time in format %H-%M-%S  from different file path that look as follow:

```
u'C:/Users/pivo/work/Data/Pink_Exp_2015_12031329\\2015-12-03_15-58-29_TrData.txt'


u'C:/Users/pivo/work/Data/Black_try\\2015-12-03_14-41-00_TrData.txt'
```

I can use split and point to the time, for the two cases works as follow but I am looking for a general solution

```
date_str = path1.split('_')[2]
date_str = path2.split('_')[4]
```

What's the best way to do that? Thank you

Comment: did you try any approach

Comment: @saikumarm see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

reg = r'\d+\-\d+\-\d+'
data='C:/Users/pivo/work/Data/Black_try\\2015-12-03_14-41-00_TrData.txt'
a=re.findall(reg, data)
print(a[1])
```

You need to try doing some regex patterns to find what you absolutely want.

Here is a python regex tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. I will have a look to regex library tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with the date, the following approach might also be helpful:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

filepaths = [ur'C:/Users/pivo/work/Data/Pink_Exp_2015_12031329\2015-12-03_15-58-29_TrData.txt',
    ur'C:/Users/pivo/work/Data/Black_try\2015-12-03_14-41-00_TrData.txt', 'not suitable.txt']

for full_path in filepaths:
    path, name = os.path.split(full_path)

    try:
        print datetime.strptime(name[:19], '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    except ValueError, e:
        pass
```

This would display the following output dates:

```
2015-12-03 15:58:29
2015-12-03 14:41:00
```